# Getting old calendar events back

Tags: calendar

I didn't know that the Calendar doesn't display events older than 1 month. How do I get the older events displayed?

And, can I avoid this problem in the future by exporting an archive of my calendar monthly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are viewing on an iOS device because the default setting is to only sync events one month back.

If my guess is right you can set it to sync all events in:

Settings >  Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Sync (down under the Calendars heading)